# Python IndentationError - Lambda backup

Tags: python-2.7

My AWS backup script is throwing an indentation error when I run it through http://pep8online.com.

I've been through the code and replaced all tabs with spaces, all spaces with tabs etc. However the error is persisting.

The exact error is on line 23 of my script and reads "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level".

However if I change the indents above to be 2 spaces then I am getting a different error on line 23 "indentation is not a multiple of four" and there are then errors being flagged as running all through my script.

The code I am using is below.

```
import boto3
import collections
import datetime
import time
import sys


today = datetime.date.today()
today_string = today.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')


# Set the number of days before snapshot deletion (10).
deletion_date = today - datetime.timedelta(days=10)
deletion_date_string = deletion_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')


ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
regions = ec2.describe_regions().get('Regions', [])
all_regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in regions]


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    snapshot_counter = 0
    snap_size_counter = 0
    deletion_counter = 0
    deleted_size_counter = 0

  for region_name in all_regions:
      ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region_name)

      # We only want to look through instances with the following tag key value pair: auto_snapshot : true
      instances = ec2.instances.filter(
          Filters=[
              {'Name': 'tag:auto_snapshot', 'Values': ['true']}
                  ]
              )

      volume_ids = []
      for i in instances.all():

          for tag in i.tags:  # Get the name of the instance
              if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
                  name = tag['Value']


          vols = i.volumes.all()  # Iterate through each instances volumes
          for v in vols:
              print('{0} is attached to volume {1}, proceeding to snapshot'.format(name, v.id))
              volume_ids.extend(v.id)
              snapshot = v.create_snapshot(
                  Description = 'AutoSnapshot of {0}, on volume {1} - Created {2}'.format(name, v.id, today_string),
                  )
              snapshot.create_tags(  # Add the following tags to the new snapshot
                  Tags = [
                      {
                          'Key': 'auto_snap',
                          'Value': 'true'
                      },
                      {
                          'Key': 'volume',
                      'Value': v.id
                      },
                      {
                          'Key': 'CreatedOn',
                          'Value': today_string
                      },
                       {
                          'Key': 'Name',
                          'Value': '{} autosnap'.format(name)
                      }
                  ]
              )
              snapshot_counter += 1
              snap_size_counter += snapshot.volume_size

              # Now iterate through snapshots which were made by autosnap
              snapshots = ec2.snapshots.filter(
                  Filters=[
                      {'Name': 'tag:auto_snap', 'Values': ['true']
                      }
                  ]
              )


              for snap in snapshots:
                  can_delete = False
                  for tag in snap.tags: # Use these if statements to get each snapshot's
                                        # created on date, name and auto_snap tag
                      if tag['Key'] == 'CreatedOn':
                          created_on_string = tag['Value']
                      if tag['Key'] == 'auto_snap':
                          if tag['Value'] == 'true':
                              can_delete = True
                      if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
                          name = tag['Value']
                  created_on = datetime.datetime.strptime(created_on_string, '%Y/%m/%d').date()

                  if created_on <= deletion_date and can_delete == True:
                      deleted_size_counter += snap.volume_size
                      snap.delete()
                      deletion_counter += 1

  return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something pretty badly formatted about your code, I just formatted it inside PyCharm and it now doesn't report indentation errors etc. try this:

```
import boto3
import collections
import datetime
import time
import sys


today = datetime.date.today()
today_string = today.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')


# Set the number of days before snapshot deletion (10).
deletion_date = today - datetime.timedelta(days=10)
deletion_date_string = deletion_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')


ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
regions = ec2.describe_regions().get('Regions', [])
all_regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in regions]


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    snapshot_counter = 0
    snap_size_counter = 0
    deletion_counter = 0
    deleted_size_counter = 0

    for region_name in all_regions:
        ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region_name)

      # We only want to look through instances with the following tag key value pair: auto_snapshot : true
        instances = ec2.instances.filter(
              Filters=[
                  {'Name': 'tag:auto_snapshot', 'Values': ['true']}
                      ]
                  )

        volume_ids = []
        for i in instances.all():

            for tag in i.tags:  # Get the name of the instance
                if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
                    name = tag['Value']


            vols = i.volumes.all()  # Iterate through each instances volumes
            for v in vols:
                print('{0} is attached to volume {1}, proceeding to snapshot'.format(name, v.id))
                volume_ids.extend(v.id)
                snapshot = v.create_snapshot(
                  Description = 'AutoSnapshot of {0}, on volume {1} - Created {2}'.format(name, v.id, today_string),
                  )
                snapshot.create_tags(  # Add the following tags to the new snapshot
                  Tags = [
                      {
                          'Key': 'auto_snap',
                          'Value': 'true'
                      },
                      {
                          'Key': 'volume',
                      'Value': v.id
                      },
                      {
                          'Key': 'CreatedOn',
                          'Value': today_string
                      },
                       {
                          'Key': 'Name',
                          'Value': '{} autosnap'.format(name)
                      }
                  ]
                )
                snapshot_counter += 1
                snap_size_counter += snapshot.volume_size

              # Now iterate through snapshots which were made by autosnap
                snapshots = ec2.snapshots.filter(
                  Filters=[
                      {'Name': 'tag:auto_snap', 'Values': ['true']
                      }
                  ]
              )


                for snap in snapshots:
                    can_delete = False
                    for tag in snap.tags: # Use these if statements to get each snapshot's
                                        # created on date, name and auto_snap tag
                        if tag['Key'] == 'CreatedOn':
                            created_on_string = tag['Value']
                        if tag['Key'] == 'auto_snap':
                            if tag['Value'] == 'true':
                                can_delete = True
                        if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
                            name = tag['Value']
                            created_on = datetime.datetime.strptime(created_on_string, '%Y/%m/%d').date()

                            if created_on <= deletion_date and can_delete == True:
                                deleted_size_counter += snap.volume_size
                                snap.delete()
                                deletion_counter += 1

    return
```

Also there is a linter online that will tell you if there are errors like this etc. if you just copy and paste your code: https://pythonbuddy.com/.  There are also linters like pylint, flake8 etc. that can be used in terminal.

Comment: Thanks Liam, that's great.
Thanks for including the links too, really useful. :)